# Uploading BLOB url to PHP server via ajax - Cordova

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I am building a hybrid mobile app with cordova and is using the cordova camera plugin. I was able to get the blob:url for the image but hits a dead-end with uploading it to my back-end php server.

Background information:

I have two buttons that I have created to test the cordova camera api.
1 - Take Photo Btn -> Generates a blob url
2 - Upload Photo -> Suppose to upload the image captured based on the photo take to my server via ajax.

Based on my console, I am getting index:file not found and it generates a 0KB image file on my server. I am fairly new to ajax and blob so would appreciate any assistance rendered.

```
//JS CODE
uploadimgtoserver : function () {

 //x is the blobimage url blob:http://localhost:8000/cb420014-a0b9-481a-b3ea- 
   6657f7e7c98e
           var x = localStorage.getItem('data');



                 $.ajax({
                    url: 'URL', 
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'file':x},

                    success: function (data) { 
                    console.log(data);
                    },
                     });
}
        };



//php code
$data = $_POST['file'];
$data = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data); 
$file = uniqid() . '.jpg'; 
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: Just telling us that something is “hitting a dead end” is not an actual question. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @04FS I have edited it accordingly

Comment: PHP has $_FILE that is the basis of POST based file uploads. You need to read the sections of the PHP manual that deal with file uploads, as there are helpers like `move_uploaded_file`.  Even a cursory google for `php image upload` will yield scores of results that should help.  I'd also highly recommend using symfony components like file, filesystem, finder, not to mention the numerous image specific bundles you can find on packagist.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Does the upload work properly? Is the file written to the desired location? Does it contain what you would expect to be in that file?

Comment: Can you show your form

Comment: @Nico Haase the php server for some reason could read the key that i had specified in my ajax. I tried another method and the server only produced a 42KB image file. I read somewhere that bloburl is only temporary hence i created a new blob instance but I have no idea how to properly transfer the blob file to the server and let the server decode the blob as an image.

Comment: Why should the server "decode" anything after all? Have you tried checking what is written to the file and how that differs from your input?

Comment: @Googlian there is no form all I had is two button one is take picture (using cordova camera plugin) -> Successfully retrieved the bloburl and another button is upload picture -> Ajax call

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean't the PHP script couldn't read the key that I had specified in my ajax call so only empty file was created. My concern is whether my JavaScript is correct.

Comment: So, have you checked what is sent to the backend using your browser's network console? It shows you what **exactly** is sent, so you don't have to guess

Comment: @NicoHaase My browser console only shows the response

Undefined index: file in <b>...on line 11

i suspect something is wrong with my javascript.

Comment: And it does not send any data with the request?

Comment: In my previous comment, I should have referenced $_FILES.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited my javascript and managed to call the PHP back-end server. But it seems like the blob file from my client isn't uploaded at all. I checked my server only a 42KB empty image file was created with no data.

Comment: Don't use `$_FILES` - you are not sending `multipart/form-data` - there is no file, just a big string in the `$_POST` var. What exactly is there PHP-side? Show the output of `print_r($_POST['file'])`. Why you have no error handling in the file? You giving way too little information and all this is just guessing......

Comment: @DanFromGermany 

The code is based on this https://gist.github.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/75092fbba5428fb9369fa02b75fa73b2


I managed to retrieve the blob:url for my image but I have no idea how to successfully post and write the image on my server.

Comment: I think you need to switch to sending multipart/form-data. You say in your x is not a real blob but an url to the blob. Anyways, if you don't debug the stuff people comment here, we can't help you. You say for example an "empty" image with 42KB Data is generated... What is this 42kb data? Maybe a PHP error, we don't know.